# Distribute list of tasks evenly among list of employees

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, loops, load-balancing

I want to distribute a list of alerts/notifications evenly amongst a list of active employees to try ensure that everyone has a similar number of responsabilities. I currently recieve a list of the alerts to be assigned and the active users plus the number of activities each one has currently assigned. As of right now I have only managed to achieve the distribution in the same order as the for loop iterates, but I can't think of a way to evenly do this.

For example:

- e1 has 1 alert
- e2 has 1 alert
- e3 has 3 alerts

I want to assign tasks to e1 and e2 until they reach 3 and then the loop can continue as normal until it runs out of alerts.

Employee is a dictionary containing {"id": "oid", "alerts": int}
unassignedAlerts is just a list of ObjectIds

Code:

```
for alert in unassignedAlerts:
                for employee in activeEmployees:
                    if employee ["alerts"] > maxAlerts:
                        maxAlerts = employee["alerts"]
                    elif employee ["_id"] in activeUsers:
                        operations.append(
                            UpdateOne({"_id": alert}, {"$set": {"employeeResponsible": employee["_id"], "status": "assigned"}})
                        )
                        employee["alerts"] += 1
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic load balancing problem. The brute force method is to repeatedly find the employee who currently has the minimum number of alerts:

```py
for alert in unassigned_alerts:
    assigned_employee = min(active_employees, key=lambda e: e["alerts"])
    assigned_employee["alerts"] += 1
    ...
```

This runs in `O(m*n)` time, where `m` is the number of unassigned alerts and `n` is the number of active employees.

You can improve this to `O(m*log(n))` by using a min-heap data structure to find the optimal employee. Python offers a built-in min-heap implementation in the [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html). To use it, you could store the employees as a list of pairs (tuples of length 2), where the first element is the number of alerts and the second element is the dictionary containing other information:

```py
import heapq


active_employees = [
    (3, {"name": "John", "id": 1}),
    (5, {"name": "Jane", "id": 2})
]
heapq.heapify(active_employees)

for alert in unassigned_alerts:
    num_alerts, assigned_employee = heapq.heappop(active_employees)
    heapq.heappush(active_employees, (num_alerts+1, assigned_employee))
    ...
```

Finally, I should mention that you do not need to always assign to the employee with minimum load. You can achieve a very good balance (with high probability) by simply picking two employees at random and then assigning to the one with less work. See this excellent [blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-power-of-two-choices-load-balancing-algorithm/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this since I really care about performance since this will be running on a serverless cloud function, so literally time is money.

Comment: In the end, i just went full random like you mentioned in the last paragraph with the assignment and I found that it works decently well without sacrificing performance.

Comment: @DiegoTrigueros Yes, the power of two random choices is great because it only requires constant time for each assignment and does quite well in expectation.